# How do I simply refresh a view in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm brand new to backbone and just learning the basics. I am building an image gallery with backbone. I am displaying a large version of an image. The routing is working properly. When a url is passed with an id the appropriate JSON is loaded into the model and the html is injected into the dom. Everything displays as expected.

However, I tried entering a url for the JSON for an image that didn't exist and noticed that the view still rendered but *with the previously rendered view's properties (image url) still present*. How do I ensure that the view is refreshed - all empty properties? Or is it the model that needs to be refreshed?

Note: I am re-using the view to avoid the overhead of creating and dystroying the view itself.

Here is the view in question:

```
var ImageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile(
        '<div class="galleryImageSingle">'+
        '<h2>{{title}}</h2>' +
        '<img id="image" src="{{imageUrl}}" class="img-polaroid" />' +
        '<div class="fb-share share-btn small"><img src="img/fb-share-btn-    small.png"/></div>'+
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="black-overlay"></div>'
    ),

    initialize: function  () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        //this.model.on('change',this.render,this); 
    },

    fbSharePhoto: function () {
        console.log('share to fb ' + this.model.attributes.shareUrl)
    },

    close: function () {

      //this.undelegateEvents();
      this.remove();
    },

    render: function () {

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        this.delegateEvents({
            'click .fb-share'               : 'fbSharePhoto',
            'click .black-overlay'          : 'close'
        });

        return this;
    }
})
```

Here is the router:

```
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ""                      :           "dashboard",
        "image/:iId"            :           "showImage", 
    },

    initialize: function  () {

        // this.galleriesCollection = new GalleriesCollection(); //A collection of galleries
        // this.galleriesCollection.fetch();

        this.imageModel         = new Image(); 
        this.imageView          = new ImageView ({  model: this.imageModel });

    },

    dashboard: function () {
        console.log('@AppRouter show dashboard - hide everything else');

        //$('#app').html(this.menuView.render().el);
    },

    showImage: function (iId) {
        console.log('@AppRouter showPhoto() ' + iId);
        this.imageModel.set('id', iId);
        this.imageModel.fetch();
        $('#imageViewer').html(this.imageView.render().el);
    }


});
```

Is is it that the model still has the old info or the view, or both?

For extra credit, how could I detect a failure to fetch and respond to it by not triggering the corresponding view? Or I am I coming at it wrongly?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Looks like I found something that works. I think just the process of framing the question properly helps to answer it. (I'm not allowed to answer the question so I'll post what I found here)

It appears that its the model that needs refreshing in this case. In the app router when I call the showImage function I clear the model and reset its values to default before calling fetch and this did the trick. Ironically the trick here is showing a broken image tag.

```
showImage: function (iId) {
console.log('@AppRouter showPhoto() ' + iId);
this.imageModel.clear().set(this.imageModel.defaults);
this.imageModel.set('id', iId);
this.imageModel.fetch();
$('#imageViewer').html(this.imageView.render().el);
}
```

For my own extra credit offer: In the event of an error (if needed fetch() accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash). Still definitely open to hearing about a way of doing this thats baked in to the framework.

Comment: Could you perhaps ask another question for your extra credit offer?  It wouldn't be helpful to give an answer to that, which isn't answering your question.  You should be able to answer your own question in a few hours.

Comment: I have 'many' other questions about backbone but I think they are not closely related enough to my original question to be grouped with it. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: Note that [an empty response or a HTTP error will not update the model data](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-81).

Answer (score 0):

You can just update the model like this:

```
ImageView.model.set(attributes)
```